# jQM vertical scrollbar always visible

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, scrollbar

I'm developping a mobile application with jQM and I have simply imported it in an android web view. I want to make my vertical scrollbar always visible on a scrollable div, not only when scrolling. I have read the other threads, but they did not help me. Any suggestions?